# Need to restore Report List page in Experience Cloud

Tags: community, reporting, community-builder, experience-builder-page, experience-cloud

I created an Experience cloud with Customer Servce Tempate. I accidentally deleted page: Reports > Report List > (page variation) Report List

Now I'm trying to restore this page. I created by myself page variation with type Report List, but when I try to open it even in Experience Builder I receive an error:

```
Error ID: 1794849773

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: siteforce:designTimeMode$controller$handlePageLoadingError [Cannot read property 'match' of undefined]
Callback failed:  serviceComponent://ui.comm.runtime.components.aura.components.siteforce.controller.PubliclyCacheableComponentLoaderController/ACTION$getPageComponent
Failing descriptor: {siteforce:designTimeMode$controller$handlePageLoadingError}
```

**I need to restore/rebuild this Report List page.**

What I tried:

1. I tried to find helpful metadata related to Reports page in my IDE (Intellij Idea) in new Experience cloud to deploy it to my target Cloud. But I didn't find.
2. I tried to create a list of Object records. But report isn't a usual Object, I can't create just an Object List.
3. Tried to create a blank page and add component Report List but the same error occures.

I know that I can create new Experience Cloud with existing Reports List and rebuild whole Cloud but I bet there's an easier way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. Here is solution:

1. Create new page variation with preconfigured page Report List. Or create blank page and add component "Report list" to it.
2. Then set this page as default page variation (it's important).

That's all.